# Buffer overflow detected - mongorestore

Tags: mongodb, mongorestore

I'm trying to restore a mongodump (size 5.4GB) using mongorestore. The process runs till 32% and then exits with the error : buffer overflow detected. What is the cause of this problem and how do I restore the complete database?
[image]

Comment: what version of mongorestore is being used?

Comment: my version is 2.6.10